# Calculating goal difference in football game LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How to calculate goal difference for each team in a group for each game using LINQ

This is what I got so far, this is just a sum of given goals, not taken.

```
GoalDifference =
    context.Games
        .Where(u => u.HomeTeam == t.TeamId)
        .Sum(t1 => t1.HomeGoals) +
    context.Games
        .Where(u => u.AwayTeam == t.TeamId)
        .Sum(t1 => t1.AwayGoals);
```

Comment: I think some more details are needed. Specifically, what data type is a `Game` (what properties does it have), and likewise for a `Team`? To solve this you will have to use information which might be present in your object model, but which you haven't used in your question.

Comment: What kind of difference ? can you add couple scores and the expected result that would help us help you

Comment: Some more details about your business logic is needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have two different ids, one fore home team and other for away team. Then

```
GoalDifference =
    context.Games
        .Where(u => u.HomeTeam == homeTeamId && u.AwayTeam == awayTeamId )
        .Sum(t1 => Math.Abs(t1.HomeGoals - t1.AwayGoals))
```

or  you need to have MatchId for both, then

```
 GoalDifference =
    context.Games
        .Where(u => u.MatchId == matchId )
        .Sum(t1 => Math.Abs(t1.HomeGoals - t1.AwayGoals))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think by saying `goal difference` you want this:

```
GoalDifference =
//Home goal difference
context.Games
    .Where(u => u.HomeTeam == t.TeamId)
    .Sum(g1 => g1.HomeGoals - g1.AwayGoals) +
//Away goal difference 
context.Games
    .Where(u => u.AwayTeam == t.TeamId)
    .Sum(g1 => g1.AwayGoals- g1.HomeGoals);
```

please notice you are selecting games not teams within `sum`, so `g1` is a better name than `t1`